# How to find div from one component from different component - vuejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

Consider i have multiple Vue.js components.

```
<loginFields></loginFields>
<submitButton></submitButton>
```

Now, after clicking submitButton (which in fact is a div with unique id) i want a method to be started to check values of loginFields.
Component loginFields has v-for directive inside which creates multiple input fields like username or password. 
What i want to achieve is to get value of user loginField and password loginField and pass it to method from submitField.
With jQuery it would be easy - call $('#userLoginField').val() and it is done.
I believe there are two ways to do it in vue, however i guess they are both not best approaches:

1. create Bus and on clicking submitButton emit an event which starts cascade of events which finally comes back to submitButton with value of all input fields. I think it is quite messy.
2. Call this.$parent.$refs of submitField and then get refs of inputFields component, search it for all other refs, grab value. It is messy too.

Is there a short and clean solution like jQuery version to easily get data from other children of same parent or siblings? Each sibling may have unique id, be a part of same/different class so it can be easily identified.

Kalreg.

Comment: This might help: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/vue/get-data-from-another-component

Comment: if design well, I think parent component can handle the data/event of the child components easily.

Comment: I dont want to handle component data from parent to child but from children of compA to child of component B, whilr compA and compB are siblings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the simplest way (i.e., least amount of "Vue wiring") is using the native form's `submit`-event, which includes the form's elements (including children of `<login-fields>`) in `event.target.elements`. The `submit`-event handler could validate those elements' values as needed.

```
// in <login-form>
methods: {
  submit(e) {
    // Get elements that have a "name" attr
    const elems = Array.from(e.target.elements).filter(el => el.name);

    // Create dictionary of those elements' values
    const values = elems.reduce((p,c) => {
      p[c.name] = c.value;
      return p;
    }, {});

    if (this.validate(values)) {
      // submit form
    } else {
      // don't submit...show error
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  }
}
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/xomrorln9q)

Comment: Your way is good but works only if form exists (in my particular example). But if i add a Title component that changes on wrong login there is no idea to point it a change title other way than emiting  an event. Or am i wrong? Consider title component has #title id.

Comment: Login fields typically are contained in a `<form>`, which provides facilities you would have to otherwise implement. It's possible to not use a `<form>`, but then you'd probably be reinventing the wheel. Regarding the title component, there's nothing wrong with emitting an event to signal a login failure. Setting a text field with an error message from an event detail is trivial to do. But there are other ways of doing this without necessarily using an event. You should probably ask that as a separate question to get better answers.